# Can't get netbeans to link GLEW properly

Tags: c++, opengl, netbeans, linker, glew

I am running a basic openGL program that compiles and runs fine in command prompt with the command

g++ gltest.cpp -std=c++11 -lglew32s -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -o gltest.exe

but when I try to use it in netbeans it gives me a bunch of "undefined reference to `_imp____glewCreateShader'" errors. All references to glew functions.

I have the needed libraries put in the linker options

[image]

[image]

here is the code:

```
// g++ gldrop.cpp -std=c++11 -lglew32s -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -o gldrop.exe 

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <iostream>
#include "gl\glew.h"
#include "gl\glfw3.h"
#include "shaderM.cpp"
#include "glm\glm\gtc\matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm\glm\glm.hpp"

#include "data.cpp"

GLFWwindow* window;

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
//initialize GLFW
if (!glfwInit())
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLFW \n";
    return -1;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

//create GLFW window
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "GL", NULL, NULL);

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
glewExperimental = true;

//initialize GLEW
if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
{
    std::cout << "failed to initialize glew";
    return -1;
}

glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

//background
glClearColor(0.4f, 0.3f, 0.7f, 0.0f);

//depth test
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//takes fragments closer to the camera
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

//Vertex array object                                                
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

//Vertex buffer
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//color buffer
GLuint colorbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_color_buffer_data), g_color_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//create shaders and attach them to a program object
GLuint program = rigShadersToProgram();

GLuint matrixID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
//projection matrix 45 degree FoV, 4:3 ratio, display range 0.1 - 100
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(70.0f, 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
//camera matrix
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
                    glm::vec3(4,3,-3), //camera is at (4,3,-3)
                    glm::vec3(0,0, 0), //looks at origin
                    glm::vec3(0,1, 0)  //head is up
                    );
//model matrix identity matrix
glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
//model-view-projection
glm::mat4 MVP   = projection * view * model;

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    //clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //use the compiled shaders
    glUseProgram(program);
    //send transformation matrix to currently bound shader 
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);

    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,          //index 
        3,          //size
        GL_FLOAT,   //type
        GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
        0,          //stride
        0           //array buffer offset
    );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorbuffer);

    glVertexAttribPointer(
        1,          //index 
        3,          //size
        GL_FLOAT,   //type
        GL_FALSE,   //normalized?
        0,          //stride
        0           //array buffer offset
    );

    //draw triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3); //start @ vertex 0, 3 verticies

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorbuffer);
glDeleteProgram(program);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

}

Not sure why it won't recognize the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you download glew32? 
maybe you downloaded the Visual C version if not you could've unpacked the wrong version (64 bit).

Another thing I've heard (try this first)
I've had issues with glew32s on mingw and for some reason it doesn't work, use regular glew32. It should still work with the preprocessor and compiles statically without any issue.

Comment: I re-downloaded all the library files to make sure and I'm getting the same errors. Non-static glew gives me the same errors. The crazy thing is it compiles and runs with MinGW if I use command prompt.

Comment: Are they the same copy of mingw? And mainly are the flags in the same order? GCC/G++ is very picky about this